# how to protect user from editing others blog posts in django?

Tags: django

I am making a blog with django. The people who are the owner of the blog post can only edit the blog post. how to protect the route? should I make a custom middleware or there is an easy way

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: thanks bro. will keep that in mind @BearBrown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create  mixin.  It will be something like:

```
class IsOwnerMixin(object):
    permission_denied_message = _("You are not the owner of this blog - you cannot edit it")

    def dispatch (self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.get_object().owner != request.user:
            raise PermissionDenied(self.get_permission_denied_message())
        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_permission_denied_message(self):
        """
        Override this method to override the permission_denied_message attribute.
        """
        return self.permission_denied_message
```

See docs for more info: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/class-based-views/mixins/

Answer (score 1):

You can create a mixin for this purpose. If you are using functional views then function decorator can do the trick while you can use mixins for class-based views.

For understanding, here is an example:

## mixin

```
class IsPermittedMixin(object):
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            //check the permission of the user
                return super(IsPermittedMixin, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
        raise PermissionDenied()
```

## views

In your views you can use this mixin as:

```
class EditBlog(IsPermittedMixin, View):
    //do something
```

Comment: The mixins should inherit from the `Python's built-in object` type. So the base class for the mixin is default python object type. Checking the `MRO(Method Resolution Order)` for the `EditBlog` class, we can see `<class ‘object’>` in it. Hence `IsPermittedMixin` inherits from the `object` super class by using `super`.